# Latex code for a coloured checkerboard doesn't work

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to recreate the image below which is a 10-by-13 checkerboard using 4 colours. I also include the code. Latex keeps complaining of 'Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)' and then indicates something wrong with '}'.  I would appreciate some help finding the error, thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \def\m{10}
        \def\n{13}
        
        % Define the custom colors
        \definecolor{color0}{named}{black}
        \definecolor{color1}{named}{gray}
        \definecolor{color2}{named}{red}
        \definecolor{color3}{named}{green}
        \definecolor{color4}{named}{black}
        
        % Draw and fill the colored squares
        \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\m-1} {
            \foreach \j in {0,1,...,\n-1} {
                \pgfmathtruncatemacro\colorindex{mod(int(\i*\n+\j), 5)}
                \fill[draw=black, line width=0.7pt, fill=color\colorindex] (\j, \i) rectangle (\j+1, \i+1);
            }
        }
        
        % Draw the outline of the rectangle
        \draw[line width=1pt] (0, 0) rectangle (\n, \m);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{A colored rectangle with a repeating pattern.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Colored rectangle]

Comment: Add `[parse=true]` to the outer `\foreach` loop. The end of the iteration (`\m-1` and `\n-1`) needs to be evaluated firsts before you can use the `...` syntax with it. Alternatively, you can use `\inteval{\m-1}` (with an uptodate TeX distribution) or even `\pgfinteval` (the same but provided by PGF).

Comment: Could you edit my code to show me how to make these changes? Thank you.

Comment: Please show what you have tried. This is not a "do it for me" site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have an expressions after the `...` in a `\foreach` loop.

You can ask it to parse it first:

```
\foreach[parse=true] \i in {0,1,...,\m-1} {
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,\n-1} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\colorindex{mod(int(\i*\n+\j), 5)}
    \fill[draw=black, line width=0.7pt, fill=color\colorindex] (\j, \i) rectangle (\j+1, \i+1);
  }
}
```

(It still applies for the inner loop which is why it's not needed there.)

You can also use `\inteval` (with an uptodate TeX distribution, without it you need to load the `xfp` package or use `\pgfinteval` which is the same but provided by PGF).

This makes it so that the `\foreach` only “sees” the result of that evaluation.

```
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\inteval{\m-1}} {
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,\inteval{\n-1}} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\colorindex{mod(int(\i*\n+\j), 5)}
    \fill[draw=black, line width=0.7pt, fill=color\colorindex] (\j, \i) rectangle (\j+1, \i+1);
  }
}
```

---

Note that in both cases the resulting TikZ picture is too wide for the standard line width, I suggest using

```
x = \linewidth/\n, y = \linewidth/\n
```

and

```
trim left = 0pt, trim right = \linewidth
```

to make the image fit the linewidth (of the page) and ignore the linewidth (of a line in TikZ) for the left and right side of the picture.

---

The style `scale xy` makes sure that the diagram doesn't generate squares that are bigger than 1 cm × 1 cm. But it will not apply the same check for `trim right`.

I've added the `geometry` package to show the text area.

If you use another class or `\linewidth`, this may not be necessary of course.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}
\tikzset{
  scale xy/.style={% only scale down, don't scale up
    x={min(1cm,\linewidth/(#1))},
    y={min(1cm,\linewidth/(#1))}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\m{10}
\def\n{13}
\tikzset{scale xy=\n, trim left=0pt, trim right=\linewidth}

% Define the custom colors
\definecolor{color0}{named}{black}
\definecolor{color1}{named}{gray}
\definecolor{color2}{named}{red}
\definecolor{color3}{named}{green}
\definecolor{color4}{named}{black}


% Draw and fill the colored squares
\foreach \i in {0,1,...,\inteval{\m-1}} {
  \foreach \j in {0,1,...,\inteval{\n-1}} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\colorindex{mod(int(\i*\n+\j), 5)}
    \fill[draw=black, line width=0.7pt, fill=color\colorindex] (\j, \i) rectangle (\j+1, \i+1);
  }
}

% Draw the outline of the rectangle
\draw[line width=1pt] (0, 0) rectangle (\n, \m);
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A colored rectangle with a repeating pattern.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: This gives me an error: Undefined control sequence \interval  {\n -1}

Comment: @Marcus It's `\inteval` (like evaluation) not `erval`.

Comment: Yields the error: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \inteval 
                    {\n -1}
l.32 }

Comment: @Marcus Have you tried loading the `xfp` package (`\usepackage{xfp}`) as advised in my answer?

Comment: Yes, that works thanks.